# How to get the UNIX time from datetime string with timezone in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, timestamp

I want to get the UNIX timestamp from a datetime string, for example '2021-11-20T12:42:00-08:00'.
I googled the solution for this, but not found the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using python-dateutil this is trivial

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
dt = parse('2021-11-20T12:42:00-08:00')
timestamp = dt.timestamp()

# in py2.7 you cannot use .timestamp so the following should work
import pytz
timestamp = time.mktime(dt.astimezone(pytz.utc).timetuple())
```

Comment: Is it OK in python 2.7? I got one error 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'timestamp'

Comment: nope timestamp came about in 3+ ... ill edit with py2.7  version

Comment: I got the number 1637412120 after a ran the above code, but when I ran the sql 'select FROM_UNIXTIME(1637412120)' in MySql, the datetime is 2021-11-20 12:42:08. Not sure it is correct.

Comment: you should have gotten 1637469720.0

Comment: it's really astonishing that Python 2 couldn't even parse UTC offsets with strptime... it's damn ISO format! ^^ Besides, if you use dateutil, it also as a UTC time zone. You don't need dateutil *and* pytz.

Comment: Thanks for all replies. Not sure what's the error with my code.  Finally I resolved this problem using the following code.

```python
epoch = parser.parse('1970-01-01')
dt = parser.parse(str_datetime)
dt = dt.astimezone(pytz.utc)
dt = dt.replace(tzinfo=None)
return (dt - epoch).total_seconds() * 1000
```